# How to install Xdebug on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to install `xdebug` on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xdebug
```

and getting following error:

> Need to get 806 kB of archives. After this operation, 4.423 kB of
>   additional disk space will be used. Err:1
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64
>   php-xdebug amd64 2.5.5-3+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1   404  Not Found
>   E: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xdebug/php-xdebug_2.5.5-3+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get
>   update or try with --fix-missing?

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

First, you need to update local packages using the following command:

```bash
sudo apt update
# OR
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install `xdebug` with the following command:

```bash
sudo apt install php-xdebug
```

And configure it as:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/php/{YOUR_PHP_VERSION}/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

Add the following code into it:

```bash
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9005 #if you want to change the port you can change
```

Note: Directory `20151012` is most likely to be different for you. `cd` into `/usr/lib/php` and check which directory in this format has the `xdebug.so` file inside it and use that path.

And then restart the services:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm
sudo systemctl restart nginx # If you are using nginx server
sudo systemctl restart apache2 # If you are using apache server
```

**UPDATE 2024/01/11:**
In Xdebug3 you have to set the following xdebug.ini

```bash
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.client_port = 9005 #if you want to change the port you can change
```

Comment: The OP already is installing it using apt. You answer don't solve the problem.

Comment: for php8.0 xdebug, 
`sudo nano /etc/php/8.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini`
1st line is:
`zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so`

Comment: I missed to update packages before installing xdebug which fixed for me. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I use the following method and it works
retrieve content from php info

```
$ php -i> info.txt
```

copy all the text in the info.txt file then enter the xdebug [installation wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php)
and follow the ranks available there.

will look like this

```
Download xdebug-2.7.2.tgz
Install the pre-requisites for compiling PHP extensions.
On your Ubuntu system, install them with: apt-get install php-dev autoconf automake
Unpack the downloaded file with tar -xvzf xdebug-2.7.2.tgz
Run: cd xdebug-2.7.2
Run: phpize (See the FAQ if you don't have phpize).

As part of its output it should show:

Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718
If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.

Run: ./configure
Run: make
Run: cp modules/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php/20170718
Update /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini and change the line
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
```

Comment: that wizard is really helpful!

Comment: Dont know how many times I've been installing xdebug, but first time I see this. Seems very helpful!

Comment: You need to run phpize for the required PHP version as in https://xdebug.org/docs/faq#api

Answer (score 8):

**How to install Xdebug on Ubuntu**

If none of the above solutions worked for you, then your last resort might be to use `pecl`

If you don't have `pecl` installed already:

```
sudo apt -y install php7.3-dev php-pear // replace php7.3 with your version
```

Run `pecl` to install `xdebug`:

```
sudo pecl install xdebug
```

At the end of the installation, you may see this output:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-3.0.2
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so" to php.ini
```

Open your php.ini file, add the zend_exntension line at the very bottom (skip if pecl was able to place it already):

```
sudo vim /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini // again replace 7.3 with your version
```

Finally, restart your webserver, or PHP-FPM, depending on what you are using.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my issue ton install xdebug for php7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Working for Ubuntu 20.04 and PHP 7.2

Comment: ps: php --ini to find it

Answer (score 6):

I think that you should update the local package index with the latest changes made in the repositories first by typing the following command :

```
sudo apt update
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The APT package index is essentially a database of available packages from the repositories defined in the /etc/apt/sources.list file and in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory.

[Credits](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt.html.en)

Answer (score 3):

Due to `php8.x` changes, it is highly recommended to configure `php.ini` directly and after installation of *xdebug*:

`sudo nano /etc/php/8.3/cli/php.ini`

In case you are using a web-server like *apache* it is required to repeat all steps for `php/8.x/apache`.

```bash
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.idekey="xdebug"
```

Comment: After hours of searching, finally and simply, ... well done.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this answer, please bear in mind that there are significant changes between xdebug 2 and xdebug 3. There is upgrade guide provided by XDebug here: http://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Answer (score 1):

Update for php 7.4.8: In the Xdebug configuration file

```
/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

I had to add the line:

```
xdebug.force_display_errors = 1
```

As Xdebug wouldn't work instead.

Answer (score 0):

please, disable ppa/php and run `sudo apt install php-xdebug`

Comment: Removing ppa/php is certainly not what he wants... There are other alternatives (see others answers).